google recaptcha v3 not working correctly when using an if statement (Laravel-inertia)
when I want to check the score of the client inside if statement I always get timeout-or-duplicate error. but when I check the score outside of the if statement it works fine.
this is the code when checking the score outside of the if statement:
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        $endpoint = config('services.google_recaptcha');

        $response = Http::asForm()->post($endpoint['url'], [
            'secret' => $endpoint['secret_key'],
            'response' => $value,
        ])->json();

        dd('outside of if statement', $response);

        if(!($response['success'] and ($response['score'] > 0.5))) {

            $fail('Something went wrong! please try again later.');

        }
    }

/* 
"outside of if statement" // app\Rules\Recaptcha.php:25
array:5 [▼ // app\Rules\Recaptcha.php:25
  "success" => true
  "challenge_ts" => "2024-12-26T19:58:05Z"
  "hostname" => "localhost"
  "score" => 0.9
  "action" => "login"
]
*/

when I check the score inside of the if statement:
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        $endpoint = config('services.google_recaptcha');

        $response = Http::asForm()->post($endpoint['url'], [
            'secret' => $endpoint['secret_key'],
            'response' => $value,
        ])->json();

        if(!($response['success'] and ($response['score'] > 0.5))) {

            dd('inside of the if statement', $response);

            $fail('Something went wrong! please try again later.');
        }
    }


/*
"inside of the if statement" // app\Rules\Recaptcha.php:29
array:2 [▼ // app\Rules\Recaptcha.php:29
  "success" => false
  "error-codes" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "timeout-or-duplicate"
  ]
]
*/


The dd and if statement wouldn't make a difference, since the response has already been retrieved at that point. Most likely it's a different issue with the recaptcha process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308499/i-got-timeout-or-duplicate-error-using-recaptcha-v3 mentions that error happens when the recaptcha token expires

Ensure your $value is really the "g-recaptcha-response" field's value.
Ensure you are NOT under middle-man attack, in which case:

the attacker already used and/or tried the "value",
hence your use is considered a "duplicate",
and any duplicate is ignored by Google's side.

Ensure you submit the form before the "value" expires.
